# Facebook connect: Is it ok for users to see client id of my application? Also should the verification code be sent to users or not

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook connect for users to sign in to my website. I am using java. Facebook documentation says users should be redirected to 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING.

Is it ok if users know my client_id(my app id)?

Also for the above link, facebook redirects user to 
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI?state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK (YOUR_REDIRECT_URI as specified in oauth request). In that case user can see his access token. Is this safe?

Thank you
Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user can know this stuff, there is nothing harmful he or his friends can do with it.

Comment: What about the code that facebook responds with when we send the above request? Facebook redirects user to the following link which makes the code visible to user. Is it also safe if user views his code?
 YOUR_REDIRECT_URI?state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK

Answer (score 0):

Your appID is public, so there is no harm of people seeing it, but I would recommend using one of Facebook SDK libraries, since there is no official one for Java, you can use the [JavaScript/AJAX SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) if you want to do this on the client side.